# How to implement user interface containing four columns in ios with different content in each column?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I want to develop iphone application in which User Interface containing four columns with scrollable content vertically.

This simple idea can be implemented with UIcollectionview but i want to load different content in each column of collectionview with vertical scrolling for each.

So get me your views on the same how can I implement this?

Thanks,
Nirav Patadiya

Comment: Yes UICollectionView is the choice, in any case you will load different content using array of different contents..

Comment: @iphonic i can't get your view can you please elaborate this in detail? I can implement uicollectionview but i need to scroll each column separately with different data.

Comment: Create a Custom UICollectionViewCell, with additional UIScrollView and add data into it, so you get scrolling content in each column..

Comment: Create a Custom UICollectionViewCell, with additional UIScrollView and add data into it, so you get scrolling content in each column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done this thing using four different scrollviews.
Adding content dynamic to each scrollview.
I use following code:

```
-(void)addContentToScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollview dataToScroll:(NSDictionary*)data
{
    @try
    {
    int x=0;
            int y=0;
            int width = 80;
            int height = 80;
            int margin = 5;
            UIColor *colorName;

            if ([scrollview isEqual:scrollEvents])
            {
                colorName=[UIColor yellowColor];
            }
            else if([scrollview isEqual:scrollGroups])
            {

                colorName=[UIColor redColor];
            }
            else if([scrollview isEqual:scrollPlaces])
            {

                colorName=[UIColor greenColor];
            }
            else
            {
                colorName=[UIColor blueColor];
            }

            NSArray *arrTmp = [data valueForKey:@"call"];

            for (int i=0; i<arrTmp.count; i++)
            {

                UIImageView *imgTemp = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

                [imgTemp setBackgroundColor:colorName];
                [scrollview addSubview:imgTemp];

                 y+=imgTemp.frame.size.height+margin;
                [imgTemp release];

            }
            scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width, y);
            [colorName release];
}
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {

    }
    @finally
    {

    }
```

This global method will be called as per your requirement you just need to pass scrollview which want to add data and dictionary with data to be added into scrollview.

I hope this code can help others to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a UICustomViewCell.
follow the link 
http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/
set the flow layout as 
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

Comment: Hi @Rayapudi Chinni i'm able to create custom collectionviewcell but not getting how to enable vertical scrolling for each individual collectionview column. So if you can let me know how can i achieve this it would be great.May i use collectionview or different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have independent scrolling of each column in a single `UICollectionView` (at least not while using flow layout).

You could try having four independent `UICollectionView`s within your view controller, side by side, each of which has a single item per row.

Comment: Finally i got solution going to use four individual scrollviews with vertical scrolling enabled..Thanks guys for putting your efforts.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Please could mark the answer as accepted (using the tick button under up/down votes) if this solution was the correct one for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> You can populate your `collectionViewCells` with different content. But
>   for this,I would recommend you to use `PSTCollectionView`. [Here you can
>   check for the availability of `UICollectionView`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html) So,if you want
>   to develop an app for IOS5 and later,better idea would be [`PSTCollectionView`](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

Comment: i used this library in the same project instead of collectionviw but not found any option for the same.It would be great if you found any thing just let me know.So that I can use it.